# how to remove non printable without removing printable and some special characters,numerics

Tags: java

The below paragraph contains non-printable characters because of these non-printable characters i am unable to put above paragraph in html tags as soon as do it the UI is getting lost.

> and development, employee\personal relations and legal issues related to personnel. 23. Ensures    applicable laws, ... present and future trends, practices and systems in Human Resources and makes recommendations as appropriate. 31. Serves...

Can any body figure out the non-printable characters in that above paragraph...
i want to remove only those characters using JAVA code and not others.

Comment: homework? what have you tried?

Comment: If you cannot put that in html, how could you put that in your post?

Comment: Because the blockquoting in markdown is more forgiving of escape sequences than html.

Comment: i tried with [^\\p{L}\\p{N}].but it removes spaces and some other special characters also which i don't want to remove

Comment: Just replace '\' with '/' or '\\'

Comment: Suresh Koya -- The above paragraph is from XML file